# "Error signing request: tezos: unknown watermark tag: 19" error using signatory with tezos baker

Tags: node, tezos-client, baker, tezos-signer, remote-signer

I setup a baker on tezos and I setup a remote signer called signatory on a separate server. The baker is running fine when I am running it normally with the keys in the node. However, when I try to run the baker with remote signing from the signer node (signatory), I am getting an error that says: "Error signing request: tezos: unknown watermark tag: 19"
docs followed:
baker setup: https://opentezos.com/baking/cli-baker/#docker 
signatory: https://signatory.io/docs/file_based

Answer (score 0):

What operation (Transaction, endorsement, pre-endorsement etc) resulted in this error? and what is the signatory version you are using?

Comment: allowed operations in the config are generic, block and endorsement.
im using the latest version of signatory docker image.

Comment: I mean what was the message for which signatory threw this error? Can you share the logs from signatory?

Comment: signatory-signer-1  | time="2022-10-25T05:32:02Z" level=info msg="POST /keys/tz1gphYTnM4cseEejV6cPDs6WtKcpnEqUjo9" duration="152.952µs" hostname="51.89.133.105:6732" method=POST path=/keys/tz1gphYTnM4cseEejV6cPDs6WtKcpnEqUjo9 start_time="2022-10-25T05:32:02Z" status=400

Comment: signatory-signer-1  | time="2022-10-25T05:32:02Z" level=info msg="GET /authorized_keys" duration="36.66µs" hostname="51.89.133.105:6732" method=GET path=/authorized_keys start_time="2022-10-25T05:32:02Z" status=200
signatory-signer-1  | time="2022-10-25T05:32:02Z" level=error msg="tezos: unknown watermark tag: 18" pkh=tz1gphYTnM4cseEejV6cPDs6WtKcpnEqUjo9 raw=12af1864d9f06be6b6884cea6bc9c2e5fae19253acba5dc60bb1918ac35093629ef7788b44140c98001539e8000000008671e3dabda88332579a1ff1afc246046f4011a6a0cd5527b254ba4dd44544bd

Comment: these are the logs im getitng

Answer (score 0):

I just passed your raw message to the latest signatory and didn't get any errors. The pre-endorsement was signed successfully.
`=== RUN   TestPolicy/Vinayak_issue INFO[0000] Initializing vault                            vault=mock vault_name=mock INFO[0000] Requesting signing operation                  chain_id=NetXnHfVqm9iesp lvl=1391080 pkh=tz1LggX2HUdvJ1tF4Fvv8fjsrzLeW4Jr9t2Q request=preendorsement vault=Mock vault_name=mock INFO[0000] About to sign raw bytes                       chain_id=NetXnHfVqm9iesp lvl=1391080 pkh=tz1LggX2HUdvJ1tF4Fvv8fjsrzLeW4Jr9t2Q raw=12af1864d9f06be6b6884cea6bc9c2e5fae19253acba5dc60bb1918ac35093629ef7788b44140c98001539e8000000008671e3dabda88332579a1ff1afc246046f4011a6a0cd5527b254ba4dd44544bd request=preendorsement vault=Mock vault_name=mock INFO[0000] Signed preendorsement successfully            chain_id=NetXnHfVqm9iesp lvl=1391080 pkh=tz1LggX2HUdvJ1tF4Fvv8fjsrzLeW4Jr9t2Q request=preendorsement vault=Mock vault_name=mock.` 
Please share the output of `./signatory version`.

Comment: # signatory version
Error: unknown command "version" for "signatory"
Run 'signatory --help' for usage.
# signatory --version
Error: unknown flag: --version

Comment: remove the double hyphen before the version

Comment: same output:
# signatory version
Error: unknown command "version" for "signatory"
Run 'signatory --help' for usage.

Comment: This is not the latest signatory version. please download the images from the latest release and try again.
https://github.com/ecadlabs/signatory/releases/tag/v0.3.2-beta
or you can try the docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/ecadlabs/signatory/tags

Comment: i used this image : ecadlabs/signatory:v0.4.0-beta-rc0-amd64 and it worked. however with the image ecadlabs/signatory:latest, it didn't work. is it possible that the latest tag has an outdated image?

Comment: Yes, that was pushed in a year ago, but we changed the naming convention after that as we started building images for multiple platforms. We will remove latest tag from repo.